# undefined method `geometry' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgis

I have created a rails application using postgres database. I am using postgis extension for geo queries. The app is running successfully on my development(local) machine but after deploying my code on heroku server when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` it is throwing an error, saying `undefined method geometry for ActiveRecord ConnectionAdapters PostgreSQL`.
I have geometry datatype in some migrations for storing latitude and longitude.

Note that I have also created **[PostGIS extension](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis)** on heroku. And migrations that does not contain geometry datatype executed successfully.
My files are:

**Gemfile**

```
ruby "2.3.0"
gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'rgeo'
gem 'rgeo-activerecord', "~> 5.0.0.beta"
gem "activerecord-postgis-adapter", "~> 4.0.0.beta2"
```

psql --version is: `9.5.2` on heroku server

psql --version is: `9.4.7` on local server

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ad_development

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ad_production
  username: ad
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**create_cities migration**

```
def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :state, foreign_key: true
      t.geometry :lat_lan
end
```

`heroku run rake db:migrate` **stops here only.**

I am totally confused whether I have used inappropriate gems or I have misconfigured something. Please help!

Answer (score 12):

If using the DATABASE_URL environment variable to set the database connection string, ensure it has the **postgis://** (not postgres://) prefix.

ie. `postgis://username:password@db_server_url:5432/dbname`

Answer (score 4):

`url: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_URL', '').sub(/^postgres/, 'postgis') %>`

EDIT: 
It replaces the url scheme `postgres://somewhere.com` to `postgis://somewhere.com`. 
It changes to the GIS "protocol", like changing `http` to `https`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `postgresql` with `postgis` in your `database.yml` file for the adapter option.

E.g.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: yourapp_development
```

Comment: And you still have the problem?

Comment: But the error message says that you are using postgres adapter `undefined method geometry for ActiveRecord ConnectionAdapters PostgreSQL` and not Postgis adapter.